# Conversion from type 'Object(,)' to type 'String' is not valid when deleting cells from vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2010, implicit-conversion

I am trying to delete all cells that begin with the word hello in range B2 to T5000, however I keep getting a Conversion from type 'Object(,)' to type 'String' is not valid error.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
   Dim xlCell As Excel.Range = Nothing
    xlCell = xlWsheet2.Range("B2:T5000")

For Each cell In xlCell
    If xlCell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        If CStr(xlCell.Value).StartsWith("Hello") Then
            xlCell.Delete()
        End If
    End If
Next


                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Inside the loop should you not be using `cell` rather than `xCell` (which is the whole collection/range) ?

Comment: Thank you well spotted, but i still get the same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you are not using the local variable in the loop. It should be:

```
For Each cell In xlCell
    If cell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        If CStr(cell.Value).StartsWith("Hello") Then
            cell.Delete()
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Naming your range `xlCell` is not helping you to debug. Perhaps `xlRange` is more appropriate?

Having said that I think your enumeration is a little off. Something like this should work:

```
Dim xlRange As Excel.Range = Nothing
xlRange = xlWsheet2.Range("B2:T5000")

For Each rCell As Excel.Range In xlRange.Cells
    If rCell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        If rCell.Value.ToString.StartsWith("Hello") Then
            rCell.Delete()
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes i have renamed the range to help with problem solving,  now I get an error of Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472 on cell.Delete.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help, its really strange but its not doing anything to the cells that start with hello?  It doesnt error or anything but just isnt doing anything to the worksheet.

Comment: Please check my first post for the full code, i copy from one worksheet and paste in another and with the pasted cells i edit it, hope that makes sense?